# yolo darknet framework CUDA Error: invalid device symbol darknet: ./src/cuda.c:36: check_error: Assertion `0' failed

Tags: yolo, darknet

I'm very confused how to use yolo with darknet on ubuntu 18.0.4

I use the project https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/

My Notebook is a Dell Precision 7540 with Nvidia RTX 3000 Quadro installed 6GB GPU RAM

When I type nvidia-smi it shows

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
    |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
    | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
    |===============================+======================+======================|
    |   0  Quadro RTX 3000     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
    | N/A   46C    P8     7W /  N/A |    284MiB /  5934MiB |      5%      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
    |  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
    |=============================================================================|
    |    0      1464      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           152MiB |
    |    0      1655      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         122MiB |
    |    0      2193      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       3MiB |
    |    0      2234      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       3MiB |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I think my Cuda version is 10.1 but when I type nvcc --version it show Cuda Version 9.1 is installed.

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

I want to use the webcam demo to detect objects using the internal camera of my notebook.

The problem is that, when I run

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights
```

it says:

```
Loading weights from yolov3.weights...Done!
CUDA Error: invalid device symbol
darknet: ./src/cuda.c:36: check_error: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't know how I could fix this. I tried editing the Makefile but I don't
really know which option I should change to use my Graphic card mobile RTX 3000

Currently the Makefile has the following content:

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=0
OPENCV=1
OPENMP=0
DEBUG=0

ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
      -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
      -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
      -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]
#      -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] \ This one is deprecated?

# This is what I use, uncomment if you know your arch and want to specify
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52

VPATH=./src/:./examples
SLIB=libdarknet.so
ALIB=libdarknet.a
EXEC=darknet
OBJDIR=./obj/

CC=gcc
CPP=g++
NVCC=nvcc 
AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rcs
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread 
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -Isrc/
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC

ifeq ($(OPENMP), 1) 
CFLAGS+= -fopenmp
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1) 
OPTS=-O0 -g
endif

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

ifeq ($(OPENCV), 1) 
COMMON+= -DOPENCV
CFLAGS+= -DOPENCV
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lstdc++
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv` 
endif

ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1) 
COMMON+= -DCUDNN 
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN
LDFLAGS+= -lcudnn
endif

OBJ=gemm.o utils.o cuda.o deconvolutional_layer.o convolutional_layer.o list.o image.o activations.o im2col.o col2im.o blas.o crop_layer.o dropout_layer.o maxpool_layer.o softmax_layer.o data.o matrix.o network.o connected_layer.o cost_layer.o parser.o option_list.o detection_layer.o route_layer.o upsample_layer.o box.o normalization_layer.o avgpool_layer.o layer.o local_layer.o shortcut_layer.o logistic_layer.o activation_layer.o rnn_layer.o gru_layer.o crnn_layer.o demo.o batchnorm_layer.o region_layer.o reorg_layer.o tree.o  lstm_layer.o l2norm_layer.o yolo_layer.o iseg_layer.o image_opencv.o
EXECOBJA=captcha.o lsd.o super.o art.o tag.o cifar.o go.o rnn.o segmenter.o regressor.o classifier.o coco.o yolo.o detector.o nightmare.o instance-segmenter.o darknet.o
ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
LDFLAGS+= -lstdc++ 
OBJ+=convolutional_kernels.o deconvolutional_kernels.o activation_kernels.o im2col_kernels.o col2im_kernels.o blas_kernels.o crop_layer_kernels.o dropout_layer_kernels.o maxpool_layer_kernels.o avgpool_layer_kernels.o
endif

EXECOBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(EXECOBJA))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard src/*.h) Makefile include/darknet.h

all: obj backup results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)
#all: obj  results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)


$(EXEC): $(EXECOBJ) $(ALIB)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(ALIB)

$(ALIB): $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(SLIB): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CPP) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(ARCH) $(COMMON) --compiler-options "$(CFLAGS)" -c $< -o $@

obj:
    mkdir -p obj
backup:
    mkdir -p backup
results:
    mkdir -p results

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC) $(EXECOBJ) $(OBJDIR)/*
```

I would really appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The CUDA version from the nvidia-smi output is just the CUDA support level in the driver, it has nothing else to do with what CUDA toolkit version you may or may not have installed. And I doubt CUDA 9.1 actually supports your GPU